How to redo this algorithm style in Latex
Can you help me redo this style of algorithmic in latex:

Current result:

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    
    
    \newtcolorbox{myalgorithm}{
        colback=gray!10!white,
        colframe=gray!70!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title=Tabular Dyna-Q,
        colbacktitle=gray!70!black,
        boxrule=0.5mm,
        width=\textwidth,
        arc=3mm,
        left=5mm, 
        right=5mm,
        top=5mm,
        bottom=5mm,
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{myalgorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State Initialize $Q(s, a)$ and $Model(s, a)$ for all $s \in S$ and $a \in A(s)$
        \Loop
            \State $S \gets$ current (nonterminal) state
            \State $A \gets \epsilon$-greedy$(S, Q)$
            \State Take action $A$; observe resultant reward, $R$, and state, $S'$
            \State $Q(S, A) \gets Q(S, A) + \alpha [R + \gamma \max_a Q(S', a) - Q(S, A)]$
            \State $Model(S, A) \gets R, S'$ \Comment{assuming deterministic environment}
            \For {$n$ times}
                \State $S \gets$ random previously observed state
                \State $A \gets$ random action previously taken in $S$
                \State $R, S' \gets Model(S, A)$
                \State $Q(S, A) \gets Q(S, A) + \alpha [R + \gamma \max_a Q(S', a) - Q(S, A)]$
            \EndFor
        \EndLoop
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{myalgorithm}
    
    \end{document}


Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

the image of the algorithm is in this link https://ibb.co/b3Xxv18

How does that answer my question?

what did you mean by your question ?

What did you try using LaTeX?

Thank you for posting the code used to create that image.  But the code uses algorithmic, so I'm not seeing what your question is.

The current result doesn't look bad: it may even be better. // What don't you like about it?

@MS-SPO You told what I had in my mind :-D

@GowriSaro same wavelength is ... <( -_- )>

This was probably not produced using the algorithmic environment. Instead, use a regular list (enumerate and itemize):

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtcolorbox{myalgorithm}[1][]{
  colback=gray!10!white,
  colframe=gray!70!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  colbacktitle=gray!70!black,
  boxrule=1.5pt,
  width=\textwidth,
  arc=3mm,
  #1
}
\newcommand{\Model}{\text{Model}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myalgorithm}[title=Tabular Dyna-Q]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Initialize $Q(s, a)$ and $\Model(s, a)$ for all $s \in S$ and $a \in A(s)$
    \Loop
      \State $S \gets$ current (nonterminal) state
      \State $A \gets \epsilon$-greedy$(S, Q)$
      \State Take action $A$; observe resultant reward, $R$, and state, $S'$
      \State $Q(S, A) \gets Q(S, A) + \alpha [R + \gamma \max_a Q(S', a) - Q(S, A)]$
      \State $\Model(S, A) \gets R, S'$ \Comment{assuming deterministic environment}
      \For {$n$ times}
        \State $S \gets$ random previously observed state
        \State $A \gets$ random action previously taken in $S$
        \State $R, S' \gets \Model(S, A)$
        \State $Q(S, A) \gets Q(S, A) + \alpha [R + \gamma \max_a Q(S', a) - Q(S, A)]$
      \EndFor
    \EndLoop
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{myalgorithm}

\begin{myalgorithm}[title=Tabular Dyna-Q]
  Initialize $Q(s, a)$ and $\Model(s, a)$ for all $s \in \mathcal{S}$ and $a \in \mathcal{A}(s)$

  Loop forever:
  
  \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)},align=left,labelindent=1em,leftmargin=*,nosep]
    \item $S \gets$ current (nonterminal) state
    \item $A \gets \epsilon$-greedy$(S, Q)$
    \item Take action $A$; observe resultant reward, $R$, and state, $S'$
    \item $Q(S, A) \gets Q(S, A) + \alpha \bigl[R + \gamma \max_a Q(S', a) - Q(S, A)\bigr]$
    \item $\Model(S, A) \gets R, S'$ (assuming deterministic environment)
    \item Loop repeat $n$ times
    \begin{itemize}[label={},labelindent=1em,leftmargin=*,nosep]
      \item $S \gets$ random previously observed state
      \item $A \gets$ random action previously taken in $S$
      \item $R, S' \gets \Model(S, A)$
      \item $Q(S, A) \gets Q(S, A) + \alpha \bigl[R + \gamma \max_a Q(S', a) - Q(S, A)\bigr]$
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{myalgorithm}

\end{document}

